# Web2py : Using references with field other than id field

Tags: postgresql, data-access-layer, web2py

I see from web2py DAL document that to add a foreign key reference to a field, I have to specify

```
db.define_table('thing',
                Field('name'),
                Field('owner_id', 'reference person'))
```

Where person's schema will be

```
db.define_table('person',
                Field('name'),
                format='%(name)s')
```

The problem with this reference syntax is that, it, by default, assumes id to the referenced field in the base table. Supposing I want some attribute in the thing table to refer to the person's name attribute (or any attribute other than id), is there a way to do so?

I am working with a legacy database which has an id by itself and this id cannot be reset with the id field that web2py creates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables created by web2py use the "id" field as the primary key, so reference fields set a foreign key constraint referencing the "id" field.

If the primary key in your legacy database table is an auto-incrementing integer field but just doesn't happen to be named "id", you can still have web2py use that field as the primary key by specifying the "id" field type:

```
db.define_table('legacy_table',
    Field('my_id', 'id'), ...)
```

However, if the primary key is not a single auto-incrementing integer field, you should instead look at the documentation on [keyed tables](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables). You can specify the primary key of the table, in which case, web2py will not create or expect an "id" field. However, there are some limitations in functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Antony. Can you brief on what exactly are the limitations? I do not find the limitation details in the document as well.

Comment: See the bullet points at the end of that section of the book. The main limitation is that keyed tables can only reference other keyed tables. Also, the `update_record` method is not available for rows of keyed tables.